# Mensaje onclick con javascript no se mantiene

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código para mostrar un mensaje al pulsar cierto botón, pero el mensaje desaparece casi instantáneamente y no se puede leer correctamente:

```js
function informacion() {
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Preferencias Actualizadas!";
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <button onclick="informacion()" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
</div>
<br>

<p class="text-center" id="info"></p>
```

Comment: Como lo presentas no se ve que "*desaparece casi instantáneamente*".   Deberías cambiar el ejemplo, o revisar tu implementación original.

Comment: @Alejandro No logro emular el error, todo parece funcionar bien

Comment: lo probe en jsfiddle y funciona correctamente trata de explicarte mejor

Comment: La solución es quitar el submit ya que está realizando la operación y por eso no te da tiempo aquí al estar simulando sin contenido se muestra correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

Si no tienes mayor problema en hacer modificaciones, haz lo siguiente

1. quita el atributo submit y dejalo así como esta
2. quita el llamado a la función y solo colocale un id
3. Usa el addEventListener para vincular al boton con el evento click

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcional y que dejará el texto visible

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text-center">
  <button id="envio" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
</div>
<br>

<p class="text-center" id="info"></p>
  <script>
    const envio = document.getElementById("envio")
    
    envio.addEventListener("click", function () {
      let aviso = document.getElementById("info")
      aviso.innerHTML = "Enviado correctamente"
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haciendo lo que me has dicho sigue ocurriendo

Comment: haz el código en jsbin.com y comparte el enlace por que incluso desde aquí esta funcional totalmente

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tu boton hace un submit al darle click.

Quita el attributo de `type="submit"` y haz una prueba.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js">
    </script>
<head>
<script>
 function myFunction() {
    swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
}
</script>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```